# Spring Boot one request mapping for multiple input types

Tags: spring-boot

So Let's say that I have an endpoint:

```
POST /answer
```

Currently It only receives one answer from user.

```
{
    "question": "3+5",
    "answer": "8"
}
```

I'm curious It is possible to receive multiple answers, **for the same endpoint.**

```
[
    {
        "question": "3+5",
        "answer": "8"
    },
    {
        "question": "9+3",
        "answer": "12"
    }
]
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1. Here's the controller code that I'm using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/answer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response submitAnswer(SubmitAnswerRq rq) {
    return service.submitAnswer(rq);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `(@RequestBody SubmitAnswerRq[] rq)`

Comment: @LipingHuang I'll give it a try.

Comment: @LipingHuang Looks like the client should send the request in forms of array, even if It contains only one item in it. this is not what I wanted to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use List to receive as array..so when you have one question then send also under array:

```
[{
    "question": "3+5",
    "answer": "8"
}]
```

and same n numbers of answers you can send in request, make sure your service handle as a list and you should be good.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/answer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response submitAnswer(List<SubmitAnswerRq> rq) {
    return service.submitAnswer(rq);
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do that, but I was looking for something like Spring settings to mapping different input types for same endpoint. Besides, I use this approach for now. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this**
One answer is different from multi answers. Don't complicated simple things.

I recommend your write a new end point something like `/multiAnswer`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multiAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response submitAnswer(SubmitMultiAnswerRq rq) {
    return service.submitAnswer(rq);
}

public class SubmitMultiAnswerRq {
    private List<SubmitAnswerRq> answers;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Well.. It is more clear and I tend to use this, but I'm just curious If it is possible.

Comment: Maybe is possible. I have no idea. Springmvc automatically converts json into an object. It is unreasonable to convert different jsons into same object.